# What is the difference between the different words for street: 街，路 etc?

Tags: word-choice, characters

Some street names end with 路 and some with 街. I was curious to know if there is any difference in the meaning of the two words. When I look them up in a dictionary both say "street".

**Are they the same?
Is one used over another in particular situations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [街](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=%E8%A1%97) = street

过街 - cross the street

逛大街 - to go window shopping/to have a stroll

- [路](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=%E8%B7%AF) = road

走错路 -or- 走弯路 take the wrong path (both literally and figuratively)

走投无路 - to be at an impasse/to have no way out/to be at a dead end (again both lit. and fig.)

---

街 is more like a literal street, while 路 is equivalent to *road* but it can also be used figuratively for paths/directions in life, etc.